# How to remove separation rule on blank pages after chapter and TOC in book class?

Tags: two-column, double-sided, book-design

I don't want the separation rule on any blank pages! I'm using the standard `book` class.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{My Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ }
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{ }
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to redefine `\cleardoublepage` to make this happen:

```
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else%
     \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}\hbox{}\newpage\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}%
     \if@twocolumn\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}\hbox{}\newpage\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}\fi%
    \fi\fi%
}
\makeatother
```

And your updated MWE will be:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else%
     \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}\hbox{}\newpage\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}%
     \if@twocolumn\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}\hbox{}\newpage\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}\fi%
    \fi\fi%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{My Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ }
\lipsum[1-30]
\chapter{ }
\lipsum[1-23]
\chapter{ }
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{ }
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @cfr: I have updated the MWE now with chapter ends in both odd and even pages. There is no problem. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: so well explained that I added a question and answer including no footer/header here:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323283/how-to-remove-separation-rule-and-header-footer-on-blank-pages-after-chapter-and/323284#323284

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best way, but you can patch the `\chapter` command to set the width of the rule to `0pt` on the relevant pages using `nextpage` and `etoolbox`. For example,

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox,nextpage}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\patchcmd\chapter{\cleardoublepage}{\clearpage\cleartooddpage[\setlength\columnseprule{0pt}]\setlength\columnseprule{1pt}}{\typeout{Patched chapter successfully!}}{\typeout{Oh, no! Patch for chapter failed horribly!!}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{My Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ }
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{ }
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

[image: intermittent rule appearance]