# How to remove separation rule and header/footer on blank pages after chapter and TOC in book class?

Tags: two-column, book-design

I don't want the separation rule *and header/footer* on any blank pages! I'm using the standard book class.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{Footer}
\lhead{Header}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{My Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ }
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{ }
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/323279/how-to-remove-separation-rule-on-blank-pages-after-chapter-and-toc-in-book-class/323281#323281) question, just a little modification is made:

You need to redefine `\cleardoublepage` to make this happen and just add `\thispagestyle{empty}` to @Jagath answer:

```
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else%
     \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}\thispagestyle{empty}\hbox{}\newpage\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}%
     \if@twocolumn\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}\hbox{}\newpage\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}\fi%
    \fi\fi%
}
\makeatother
```

And your updated MWE will be:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lfoot{Footer}
\lhead{Header}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else%
     \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}\thispagestyle{empty}\hbox{}\newpage\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}%
     \if@twocolumn\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}\hbox{}\newpage\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}\fi%
    \fi\fi%
}
\makeatother

\title{My Title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{ }
\lipsum[1]
\chapter{ }
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```