# titlesec footers and headers

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, titletoc

I've read through the [`titlesec`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package, and I don't understand why my headers don't appear (in chapters, not TOC or intro) and why the page numbers on the first page of each chapter are in the center and not on the right.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[compact,pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}

        %page numbering and headers
        \newpagestyle{mystyle}{
            \setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
            \sethead[\chaptertitle][][]{}{}{\chaptertitle}
            }
        \pagestyle{mystyle}
        %

%creates the chapter heading style  
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\filcenter\bfseries\rmfamily}
    {\titlerule[1pt]%
    \vspace{2pt}%
    \titlerule
    \vspace{1pc}%
    \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
    {1pc}
    {\titlerule[1pt]
    \vspace{0.5pc}%
    \huge\bfseries\rmfamily}
    %   

%to get rid of headers on blank page after clelardoublepage 
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323284/121944
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{%
    \clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else%
     \setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}\thispagestyle{empty}\hbox{}\newpage\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}%
     \if@twocolumn\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}\hbox{}\newpage\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}\fi%
    \fi\fi%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents

\frontmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\mainmatter
\chapter{}
    \lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{}
    \lipsum[11-20]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution (hopefully): I define a `mystylefront`and a `mystylemain` pagestyles, for frontmatter and mainmatter. The first style displays the chapter title in the header, and the second displays `\chaptertitlename \thechapter`, followed by the chapter title if there's any. The code can easily be simplified if no chapter in mainmatter has a title.

Note that, for empty pages, you don't have to patch whatever: simply load the option `[clearempty]`. If you want empty pages to have a page number printed, remove this option.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
        %page numbering and headers
        \newpagestyle{mystylefront}{ % for frontmatter
            \setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
          \sethead[\chaptertitle][][]{}{}{\chaptertitle}
          }
        \newpagestyle{mystylemain}{ % for mainmatter
        \setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
          \sethead[\chaptertitlename\,\thechapter~\chaptertitle][][]{}{}{\chaptertitlename\,\thechapter~\chaptertitle}
          }
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\sethead{}{}{}
\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
}

%creates the chapter heading style
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\normalfont\huge\filcenter\bfseries\rmfamily}
    {\titlerule[1pt]%
    \vspace{2pt}%
    \titlerule
    \vspace{1pc}%
    \LARGE\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
    {1pc}
    {\titlerule[1pt]
    \vspace{0.5pc}%
    \huge\bfseries\rmfamily}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents%
\thispagestyle{empty}

\frontmatter
        \pagestyle{mystylefront}
\chapter{Introduction}
 \lipsum[1-5]
\mainmatter
        \pagestyle{mystylemain}
\chapter{}
    \lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{}
    \lipsum[11-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks promising, but a couple little issues. 1.) `contents` appears in both the header and footer, on the page of the contents. Don't need it to appear at all; 2.) I would like the page number to appear on the blank page in between chapters.

Comment: I added `\pagestyle{empty}` right before `\tableofcontents` and that seemed to do the trick for issue #1.

Comment: Actually, let's ignore problem #2. If you edit your answer to include the fix to issue #1 then I will accept your answer.

Comment: @AML: I've added a slightly  different code to have no header/footer  in the table of contents. As to issue #2, simply remove the `clearempty` option. Unless  you want only the page number (i.e. a plain style) in ‘empty’ pages?